# Como hago un cronometro para funciones en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito que después de una cierta cantidad de segundos, una función active a otra función pero que no afecte al flujo del programa, es decir, si por ejemplo uso time.sleep(10), durante 10 segundos el programa se me parara y no quiero eso, hay alguna manera en la que pueda hacerlo? Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con programación asíncrona, pero el código se te iba a complicar probablemente en muchas otras partes, pues en el momento que haces una función asíncrona todo el programa debe ejecutarse dentro de un framework asíncrono. Otra posibilidad es usar un hilo aparte que sea quien espere y lance tu función. Para más detalles sería necesario ver tu código o al menos una "mini-demo" básica de lo que pretendes

Comment: Puedes lanzar un thread separado que haga la espera, mientras en el `main` sigues haciendo otro cosa.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo (sin poco más que la información que aportas) sería usar un thread que se encargara de ejecutar tu función después de un determinado tiempo de espera.

Te dejo un código que sirve de apoyo:

```py
import threading
import time
import os

def funcion_a_la_espera(tiempo):
    time.sleep(tiempo)
    # realizar lo que quieras tras esperar <tiempo>, en este caso 10s

thread_espera = threading.Thread(target=funcion_a_la_espera, args=(10,), daemon=True)
thread_espera.start()

for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system("clear")  # linux/mac
    # os.system("cls")  # windows
    print(i)
```

Si nos proporcionas más información podremos ayudarte con algo más específico.